# PHP Multidimensional Array Sort array_reverse not working?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have a **`Multidimensional`** array that I am trying feverishly to properly sort by the date.

So far I've got:

```
usort($respArr, function($a, $b){
        $t1 = strtotime($a['PublishDate']);
        $t2 = strtotime($b['PublishDate']);
        return $t1 - $t2;
    });

array_reverse($respArr);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($respArr);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<hr />';
```

Here's some of the output from the above:

```
Array
(
[34] => Array
    (
        [Title] => o7thwd: Partnered with Internet Services Inc., to offer complete online presence! http://t.co/1SgAF66Tbf @ISI_Cloud
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/o7thwd/statuses/306088158574022656
        [PublishDate] => 2/25/2013 12:07:58 PM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => o7thwd: Partnered with Internet Services Inc., to offer complete online presence! http://t.co/1SgAF66Tbf @ISI_Cloud
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [Title] => o7thwd: Hangin with Mama Bear giving her the basics of social networking
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/o7thwd/statuses/307916797066240000
        [PublishDate] => 3/2/2013 1:14:19 PM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => o7thwd: Hangin with Mama Bear giving her the basics of social networking
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [Title] => o7thwd: o7th Web Design Articles http://t.co/plP8OkB7So
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/o7thwd/statuses/308687737400205313
        [PublishDate] => 3/4/2013 4:17:46 PM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => o7thwd: o7th Web Design Articles http://t.co/plP8OkB7So
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [Title] => o7thwd: finished up my GUI for a YUI minifier: http://t.co/7DKLoCXJHw
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/o7thwd/statuses/309309871931682816
        [PublishDate] => 3/6/2013 9:29:54 AM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => o7thwd: finished up my GUI for a YUI minifier: http://t.co/7DKLoCXJHw
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [Title] => o7thwd: o7th Web Design Articles http://t.co/QAIUO2Qjko
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/o7thwd/statuses/314356123027243008
        [PublishDate] => 3/20/2013 8:41:54 AM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => o7thwd: o7th Web Design Articles http://t.co/QAIUO2Qjko
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [Title] => SkorIn2: starting new desktop app to compliment the web app
        [Link] => http://twitter.com/SkorIn2/statuses/314718985725804545
        [PublishDate] => 3/21/2013 8:43:48 AM
        [Image] => 
        [Description] => SkorIn2: starting new desktop app to compliment the web app
    )

)
```

However, the array *is not reversed*, as you can tell above.    **Can anyone help me with this?**
 It's showing me that the array is indeed sorted by the 'PublishDate', however, in the reverse order that I need it in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The actual problem is you're not assigning the result of `array_reverse` to anything

```
// change this
array_reverse($respArr);

// to this
$respArr = array_reverse($respArr);
```

Comment: untested: `function reveseme(&$array){$array=array_reverse($array);return;} $array=array(1,2,3,4,5); reveseme($array);` This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$arr  = your array;
$sort = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['PublishDate'][$k] = $v['PublishDate'];
}

array_multisort($sort['PublishDate'], SORT_DESC, $arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

But make your date prperly formated, else this may not work. format it to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: sorry, i don't have a choice to the formatting...  this is pulled from a twitter feed