# Sort array of arrays by value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I've got an array of arrays like this :

```
Array(
    [id1] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 3
          )
    [id2] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 5
    [id3] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 1
    )
)
```

**Question :** How could I sort it by the `unique` field, so that it is converted like the one following?

```
Array(
    [id2] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 5
          )
    [id1] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 3
    [id3] => Array (
           /* details */
           [unique] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multidimensional-array-by-value-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282013/php-array-multiple-sort-by-value-then-by-key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549048/php-multidimensional-array-sort-array-reverse-not-working/15549079#15549079

Comment: lol Ryan, do you think this has been asked before? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classical task for usort function:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "id1" => Array (
        "unique" => 3
        ),
    "id2" => Array (
        "unique" => 5),
    "id3" => Array (
        "unique" => 1
        ),
    );

function cmp($a, $b)
// {{{
{
    if ($a["unique"] == $b["unique"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["unique"] < $b["unique"]) ? 1 : -1;
}
// }}}

usort($data, "cmp");
var_dump($data);
```

Prints:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unique"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unique"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["unique"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Answer (score 0):

using my custom function you can sort  array

```
function multisort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}

multisort ($your_array,"order");
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `usort()`:

```
$array = array(
    "id1" => array("unique" => 3),
    "id2" => array("unique" => 5),
    "id3" => array("unique" => 1),
);

usort($array, function ($a, $b){
    if ($a['unique'] == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['unique'] > $b['unique']) ? -1 : 1;
});

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [unique] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [unique] => 3
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [unique] => 1
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm repeating myself, sorry :D

Do not hesitate to look at libraries from frameworks.

[CakePHP] made an awesome class which is able to navigate into arrays using a string in dot syntax notation. This library is known as [**Hash**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-utility-libraries/hash.html), just look at it.

The method [**Sort**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Hash.html#_sort) is used to sort an array with keys and values depending of what you put inside the "path" attribute.
It's more useful than others functions, because it sorts the array by **keeping the indexes** and all the other subvalues contained in this array, including more dimensional sub-arrays.

For your example :

```php
$array = array(
    'id1' => array (
        'unique' => 3,
    ),
    'id2' => array (
        'unique' => 5,
    ),
    'id3' => Array (
        'unique' => 1,
    ),
);
```

Just write this :

```php
/**
 * First param: the array
 * Second param : the "path" of the datas to save.
 *  "{s}" means "Matching any kind of index", for you to sort ALL indexes matching
 *  the dot "." is used to navigate into the array like an object
 *  And "unique" is the key which you want to be sorted by its value
 * The third param is simply the order method, "ascending" or "descending"
*/
$sorted_array = Hash::sort($array, '{s}.unique', 'asc');
```

And `$sorted_array` will be equal to this :

```php
array (
    'id3' => array (
        'unique' => 1,
    ),
    'id1' => array (
        'unique' => 3,
    ),
    'id2' => array (
        'unique' => 5,
    ),
);
```